# How to replace content of <td> and <div> with new content in AJAX response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

For your understanding my issue I've put in here only the necessary code.

HTML Code :

```
<td style="text-align:center" id="brand_image_td_101">Some text goes here</td><!-- This is the td whose content need to be replaced with new content-->

<div id="brand_101"><!-- This is the div whose content need to be replaced with new content-->    
  <a href="#" id="promotion_status_101">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default brmodalbtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#BrandImageModal" id="101">On</button>
  </a>
</div>
```

The modal dialog is displayed on click of the button from above div, AJAX request goes to PHP page, from there error or success message comes, etc. etc.

Everything works fine till here. The issue I'm facing is in replacing the content of above `<div id="brand_101">`. I want to replace the content of above `<div id="brand_101">` with following content :

```
<td style="text-align:center" id="brand_image_td_101"><img src="http://web_prj.com/pqr.php/uploads/a123.jpg" width="80" height="80"></td><!-- This is the new td content-->

<div id="brand_101"><!-- This is the new div content-->
  <a href="#" id="promotion_status_101" onClick="change_promotion_status('http://web_prj.com/pqr.php', 'promotion_status', '101', '0'); return false;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Off</button>
  </a> 
</div>
```

This thing I want to achieve in jQuery functions's success response. But I'm not understanding how should I achieve this.

Following is the jQuery AJAX function that I 've written:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  var br_id = $('#brand_id').val();//This variable contains value 101
  var status = '0';
  var module_url = $('#module_url').val();//This variable contains value http://web_prj.com/pqr.php
  var upload_url = $('#upload_url').val();//This variable contains value http://web_prj.com/pqr.php/uploads/a123.jpg
  var formdata = false;
  if(window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
  }

  var formAction = form.attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'manufacturers.php',
    cache       : false,
    data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,

    success: function(response) { 
      if(response.error == 0) {  
        $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response.error_message);

      } else { 
        $('#BrandImageModal').modal('hide');
        //location.reload();       
      }
    },
    dataType:"JSON"
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

How should I replace the contents of  and  with new content created using the variables' values in AJAX function so that I could get the content as above?

Comment: `<div><td>...</td></div>` is invalid html...

Comment: hard to really understand exactly what is being replaced. Replacing a `<div>` with a `<td>` makes no sense

Comment: @MarcB:<div> is different and <td> is different. They both are not mingle dup. They both are present at two different places. You are thinking that <td> is present within <div> which is not the case here.

Comment: @charlietfl:I want to replace <td>'s old content with new content that I've mention in another <td>. Same is the case with <div>. I don't want to replace <td>'s content by <div> or vice-versa.

Comment: when you talk about dom elements and "content", then `<div> content goes here</div>` saying "I want to take the div and replace its contents with `<td>...` means you want to erase the "content goes here" and stuff in the td's.

Comment: @MarcB:Le t me explain you in a very simple way. I want to replace the HTML contained in first <td> with the HTML present in second <td>. Same is the case with <div>. I want to replace the HTML contained in first <div> with the HTML present in second <div>.

Comment: I hope you must have tried with .html() in your ajax success block ? If yes , then please share the way you did . Because that is the only way you can acheive that and if you have tried and not getting the desired result then we are here to correct those errors .

Comment: still very confusing descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misinterpreting, but you could try something like this:

```
//put the following into the the success function where you want to add new content
// create an string containing the html you want to insert
var newContent = '<a href="#" id="promotion_status_101" onClick="change_promotion_status('http://web_prj.com/pqr.php', 'promotion_status', '101', '0'); return   false;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Off</button></a> ';

// remove old content from the div. Now you just have an empty div
$('#branding-101').html('');
// add the new content to the div
$('#branding-101').html(newContent);
```

Or do you need to pull new values from the response? If that's the case, you would do the same thing, only you would build the string by concatenating values from the response text..