# What's an issue with the string and variable concatenation in jQuery/JavaScript in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, string, string-concatenation

I've following AJAX function in whose response I'm creating a new html content. For this purpose I've declared two variables and I'm assigning the concatenated values of strings and other variables to these two variables. Actually these strings I'm going to use with `.html()` method of jQuery. But I'm not able to concatenate the string and variable values properly. Can some one please guide me in this regard please?

Other things in function are working perfectly so please ignore other things. Please consider only the issue I'm facing in concatenation in AJAX success response.

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  var form = $(this);
  var br_id = $('#brand_id').val();
  var status = '0';
  var module_url = $('#module_url').val();
  var upload_url = $('#upload_url').val();
  var formdata = false;
  if(window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData(form[0]);
  }

  var formAction = form.attr('action');

  $.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'manufacturers.php',
    cache       : false,
    data        : formdata ? formdata : form.serialize(),
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,

    success: function(response) { 
      if(response.error == 0) {  
        $('#messages').addClass('alert alert-danger').text(response.error_message);

      } else { 
        $('#BrandImageModal').modal('hide');

  //For the below two statements I'm getting syntactical errors while concatenating strings and variables        
  var newdiv = '<a href="#" id="promotion_status_"+br_id+" onClick="change_promotion_status("+module_url+" , promotion_status, +"br_id+", '0'); return false;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Off</button></a> ';
  var newtd  = '<img src="+upload_url"+text(response.image_path)+" width="80" height="80">';           
      }
    },
    dataType:"JSON"
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible string delimiters: `'` and `"`. You can use either, but you cannot mix them. The one that you use for a string will need to be escaped inside, the other can be used freely.

In your case,

```
'<a href="#" id="promotion_status_"+br_id+" onClick="change_promotion_status("+module_url+" , promotion_status, +"br_id+", '0'); return false;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Off</button></a> '
```

is one big string - as can be seen from the syntax highlighting. It needs to be

```
'<a href="#" id="promotion_status_'+br_id+' onClick="change_promotion_status('+module_url+' , promotion_status, '+br_id+', \'0\'); return false;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Off</button></a> '
```

or so to work (still not producing correct HTML, as some attribute delimiters are now missing *in* the string). Same applies to `newtd`.

Also, you should *never* use inline event handler attributes - especially not dynamically created ones. The values of `module_url` and `br_id` will become *code strings*, for example if the values are strings then in the resulting HTML they would mean variables with thoses names. If you wanted them to become string literals, you would need to escape them properly (e.g. with `JSON.stringify`), but after that you also would need to HTML-escape the whole thing which is non-trivial. In summary: don't do it.

Instead, create the element (if necessary, even from an HTML string), and after that *dynamically attach an event handler*:

```
el.onclick = function(e) {
    change_promotion_status(module_url, promotion_status, br_id, '0');
    return false;
};
```

---

```
var newdiv = '<a href="#" id="promotion_status_'+br_id+'"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Off</button></a>';
var newtd  = '<img src="'+upload_url+text(response.image_path)+'" width="80" height="80">';
var $div = $(newdiv); // use jQuery to parse the HTML
$div.click(function(e) { // use jQuery for event listeners
    change_promotion_status(module_url, promotion_status, br_id, '0');
    return false;
});
$div.appendTo(…) // use jQuery for appending the new element (div, a, td, img?) to the DOM
```

Comment: As per your suggestion,I tried following code but still it gives syntactical error:
var newdiv = '<a href="#" id="promotion_status_'+br_id+' onClick="change_promotion_status('+module_url+' , promotion_status, '+br_id+', '0'); return false;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Off</button></a> ';

Comment: You're right, the `'` needed to be escaped in the `'`-delimited string (fixed now). That's why code strings are problematic…

Comment: Thanks for your help. But actually I'm not getting exactly what changes I need to make to my code so that it become workable. Can you please post necessary code in the answer? It would be of great help to me in addition to the above explanation. If you need further more details about my issue you can refer to following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285461/how-to-replace-content-of-td-and-div-with-new-content-in-ajax-response

Comment: Can we chat for some time please?

Answer (score 0):

Your mixing up your single and double quotes. For example, you have:

```
'<a href="#" id="promotion_status_" + br_id + " onClick="change_promotion_ ...
```

but it should be:

```
'<a href="#" id="promotion_status_' + br_id + '" onClick="change_promotion_ ...
```

Your string is delimited by single quotes, so make sure those are at the beginning/end of each concatenation.